# Arrowchat and Amazon instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, chat

I have a site with **codeigniter**, **mysql**, which has arrowchat installation in it.
the site (say xyz.com) is hosted in amazon environment. It has **S3** implementation for image uploads, **CDN** implementation for static file serving, **RDS**  implementation for db, **SES** for Mail sending . There is a plan to integrate **Auto scaling** for the site. I have researched on how the arrowchat will be implemented in the this scenario, as arrowchat have template and configuration file being cached, had to do some research on this for this cache sharing among the instances. I tried

a). created an **S3** bucket and mapped it to arrowchat cache folder - but it didnt go well as arrowchat library code included file in the cache directory, so being in s3 we couldnt directly include files in our arrowchat code.

b). created a subdomain **chat.xyz.com** and installed the arrowchat in that sub domain and used it in the instances. - it worked out well barring some cross domain code issues which was solved by some code fixes. Issue was, we had to manage same code in a domain and subdomain.

Are the methods I have listed proper methods? If not, what is the proper method?

Comment: Sorry but you would have to elaborate a bit more, why would you need to share the cache? I mean, imagine you set your dns to route to your ELB where you have your auto scaling machines. Without sharing cache, whats the worst that can happen? create copies of the cache on each instance? is this a real problem? Please elaborate as to why in the name of god you would need to share those cache files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ElasticCache` and share the Node pool among all the instances of the autoscale group. If the templates need processing you can't use `amazon S3` directly. (The php code on a specific instance HAS to read the template, process it and send it back). 
Pseudocode:
Associate a unique Key to each template (i.e. data/template_name ).
When a template is requested, check on Memcache if there is such Key.
Otherwise read it from `S3` and load it in the cache. Once is in the cache all the instances will be able to use that single value.